# ORDER BY date but also GROUP BY userid

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table of records I want to sort by earliest date first then by userid.

If the user associated to the date also has other records in that table I want to group those under the earliest date.

Desired output

```
Id  UserId  Date
1   2       1/1/2020
2   2       2/1/2020
3   2       3/1/2020
4   1       1/2/2020
5   1       2/2/2020
6   3       1/4/2020
7   4       1/5/2020
```

In this example UserId 2 has the earliest record in that table, so that record should be first followed by his additional records in date asc order

Comment: I think you are only looking to order by Date, UserId. You won’t need group by userid. Would you mind describing the current table you looking at

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems want :

```
select t.*
from table t
order by min(date) over (partition by userid), date;
```

Some database product doesn't support window function with `order by`, so you can do instead :

```
select t.*, min(date) over (partition by userid) as mndate
from table t
order by mndate, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want...

You could do this (sample with DB2 syntax):

```
SELECT tab.UserId, tab.Date, tab.*
  FROM DB2SIS.TABLE_NAME tab
 ORDER BY tab.Date ASC, tab.UserId ASC
```

This way UserId and Date will appear repeatedly. Instead of 'tab.*' use each field you want to show, then UserId and Date will not repeat.